# Ability for content authors to edit items without locking

Tags: role-management

Hi we want to provide access to our content authors where they can start editing any item without the need to lock it. I am able to do this when I provide them **administrator** access. Is there a way we can do this, by not making them an administrator, but by a custom role?

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding of the purpose for locking. When one editor is currently working on the item, it would be a tragedy for another editor to overwrite their changes. Locking ensures that the appropriate person is in control of the item. Granting a user "Administrator" access would be another mistake because the user bypasses workflows and has the ability to wreak havoc. Perhaps you can share more details about what challenges you have faced when requiring the users to lock the items.

Comment: @michael-west, we are a small team. only one content author and one approver (who is also legal). So the overwrite option will never happen.  As you said, don't want to give them administrator access, hence looking for alternatives.

Comment: @NightMonger If there is only one content author and only one approver then there should not be any issue with locking of an item. I don't think that approver need to lock item for review purpose only. Even though if he locked the item while reviewing then as a best practice approver should release the item one he completes the review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Micheal West said, If there is no locking functionality then When one editor is currently working on the item, it would be a tragedy for another editor to overwrite their changes. But in your case, there is a setting "RequireLockBeforeEditing" in the configuration which you can make it as false.

```
<setting name="RequireLockBeforeEditing" value="false" />
```

NOTE: This is not a Sitecore recommended practice.